# Null when injecting mock services, testing a RestController - Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito, spring-webflux

I am testing a REST controller, and I'd like to inject mock service.

But I am getting a **null** value when calling service Mock

this is my code:

Interface:

```
interface CaseManagementService {
fun createAccount(caseRequest: CaseRequestDto): Mono<CaseResponseDto>
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
class CaseManagementServiceImpl(private val clientManagementService: 
ClientManagementService) : CaseManagementService {

   override fun createAccount(caseRequest: CaseRequestDto): Mono<CaseResponseDto> {
    return clientManagementService.createAccount(caseRequest)
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("somepath")
class CaseController(private val caseManagementService: CaseManagementService) {

@PostMapping()
fun createCase(@RequestBody caseRequest: CaseRequestDto): Mono<CaseResponseDto> {
    return caseManagementService.createAccount(caseRequest)    }
}
```

The test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CaseControllerTests {
@Test
fun `createCase should return case id when a case is created`() {

    val caseManagementService: CaseManagementServiceImpl =   
    Mockito.mock(CaseManagementServiceImpl::class.java)

    val caseResponseDtoMono = Mono.just(Fakes().GetFakeCaseResponseDto())
    val requestDto = Fakes().GetFakeCaseRequestDto()

     
    `when`(caseManagementService.createAccount(requestDto).thenReturn(caseResponseDtoMono))

    var caseController = CaseController(caseManagementService)

//NULL EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE - RETURNS NULL THIS CALL
    var result = caseController.createCase(Fakes().GetFakeCaseRequestDto())

    StepVerifier.create(result)
        .consumeNextWith { r -> assertEquals(Fakes().GetFakeCaseResponseDto().id, r.id) 
    }.verifyComplete()
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closing bracket is in a wrong place: you are calling `Mono.thenReturn` (on a null Mono instance returned from `createAccount`) instead of the Mockito's `thenReturn` (I assume that's what you meant):

```kotlin
`when`(caseManagementService.createAccount(requestDto)).thenReturn(caseResponseDtoMono)
```

Second problem: you are mocking `createAccount` call for a specific instance of the `CaseRequestDto`. In the actual call you are using different instance, so the arguments do not match and the mock returns null. Try reusing the request instance, i.e.:

```kotlin
var result = caseController.createCase(requestDto)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mador. Just realised when calling the method from the controller it returns null the service call, the null exception happens when trying to verify null (StepVerifier)

Comment: I fixed the closing bracket as you recommend but still getting null from the service call

Comment: Thanks @MAfor, that was the issue, two different instances of  the same Parameter

Answer (score 0):

You have mocked the service but not injected the mocked service in the rest controller. That's why you are getting a null pointer. So, caseManagementService needs to be injected in CaseController. Below is a link where you can see the injection part. In the below code I have moved caseController variable above so that caseManagementService is injected in caseControler before it is used.

```
@SpringBootTest
class CaseControllerTests {
@Test
fun `createCase should return case id when a case is created`() {

    val caseManagementService: CaseManagementServiceImpl =   
    Mockito.mock(CaseManagementServiceImpl::class.java)
    var caseController = CaseController(caseManagementService)

    val caseResponseDtoMono = Mono.just(Fakes().GetFakeCaseResponseDto())
    val requestDto = Fakes().GetFakeCaseRequestDto()

     
    `when`(caseManagementService.createAccount(requestDto).thenReturn(caseResponseDtoMono))

   
//NULL EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE - RETURNS NULL THIS CALL
    var result = caseController.createCase(Fakes().GetFakeCaseRequestDto())

    StepVerifier.create(result)
        .consumeNextWith { r -> assertEquals(Fakes().GetFakeCaseResponseDto().id, r.id) 
    }.verifyComplete()
  }
 }
```

https://vmaks.github.io/other/2019/11/04/spring-boot-with-mockito-and-kotlin.html

Comment: But the service it is injected via the constructor of the controller class CaseController(private val caseManagementService: CaseManagementService)  , that is what u mean? Could you provide an example please

Comment: @D.B, check the code i have edited in my answer. Moved the caseController injection part earlier in the code, before the service is actually used in when call.